# Django reduce queries

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have two models, Post and Vote. Users can upvote and downvote posts.

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    poster = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    question = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    post_content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_locked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_question = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
            blank=True, null=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(
            blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_title

class Vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post')
    vote_type = models.SmallIntegerField()#-1, 0, 1
    date_voted = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

I use the following code in my view to return the posts to templates:

views.py:

```
def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(created_date__lte=timezone.now(
    ), is_question=1, is_published=1).order_by('-created_date')
    #removed the paging stuff here for simplification
    return render(request, 'homepage/index.html', {'posts': posts})
```

This just returns the posts, but I also want to check if the current user has voted or not (and possibly the sum of the vote_type column for each post which is the total number of votes for the post).

Currently I use template tags for each post to check if the current user has voted or not. This creates a lot of queries. (Currently 50 queries with 40 duplicates).

My index.html sample code:

```
{% for post in posts %}
       {% if post|userVotedThisPost:request.user.id == 1 %}
               <img id="upvote-img" class="icons" src="{% static 'img/upvote-marked.svg' %}" alt="Upvote">
       {% else %}
               <img id="upvote-img" class="icons" src="{% static 'img/upvote.svg' %}" alt="Upvote">
       {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Is there any way to query everything in the views.py and then in the template I could check like this: (if post.user_voted), so that the database is not hit each time in the for loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related) to fetch the related votes for that user.

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

Post.objects.filter(
    created_date__lte=timezone.now(),
    is_question=1, 
    is_published=1
).order_by(
    '-created_date',
).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('vote_set', queryset=Vote.objects.filter(user=request.user), to_attr='user_votes')
)
```

Then in your template, change the check to:

```
{% if post.user_votes %}
```

Comment: Is it possible to check for vote_type too? Did this user downvote, upvoted or did nothing (vote_type = 1, -1 or 0)? I mean could I change the prefetch query to return the vote_type?

Comment: The prefetch query returns a list of votes. If you only allow one vote per user per post, then the list will have one item (or it will be an empty list if the user didn't vote). You could show the vote type in the template with `{{ post.user_votes.0.vote_type }}`.

Comment: @ Alasdair is there some way to get the sum of the vote_type column for each post which is the total number of votes for the post

Comment: That would be better to ask as a separate question.

Comment: @ Alasdair here is the link to the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42303070/django-get-the-sum-of-votes-per-post