# Django get the sum of votes per post

Tags: python, django

I have two models, Post and Vote. Users can upvote and downvote posts.

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    poster = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    question = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    post_content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_locked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_question = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
            blank=True, null=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(
            blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_title

class Vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post')
    vote_type = models.SmallIntegerField()#-1, 0, 1
    date_voted = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

I use the following code in my view to return the posts to templates:

views.py:

```
def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(created_date__lte=timezone.now(
    ), is_question=1, is_published=1).order_by('-created_date')
    #removed the paging stuff here for simplification
    return render(request, 'homepage/index.html', {'posts': posts})
```

This just returns the posts, but I also want the sum of the vote_type column for each post which is the total number of votes for the post.

Currently I use template tags for each post to check for each post's votes.

My index.html sample code:

```
    {% for post in posts %}
       {{ post|total_votes|default:"0" }} 
    {% endfor %}
```

Is there any way to query everything in the views.py and then in the template I could check like this: {{post.total_votes}}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you can use [annnotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/). Generally, it would look something like

```
from django.db.models import Sum
posts = Post.objects.filter(...).annotate(total_votes=Sum('vote__vote_type'))
```

each `post` object in `posts` will then have a `total_votes` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

by using the aggregate https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/

Another solution is to have a method defined in the `Post` model to calculate the number of vote_type for a specific Post object, as below

```
# models.py
from django.db.models import Sum

class Post(models.Model):
   ......
       def total_votes(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(pk=self.id).aggregate(Sum('vote__vote_type'))
```

and in order to get the total_vote_type in temaplte

```
# post.html
{% for post in posts %} 
# Assuming in views you are passing the posts As posts = Post.objects.all()
    {{ post.total_votes.vote__vote_type__sum }}
{% endfor %}
```